# bordas de uma matriz N x N

Tags: c++, ponteiro, matriz

Gostaria de saber como faço para setar os valores da borda de uma matriz como -1. Eu tentei criar uma matriz de N+2 x N+2, e fazer com um for só, percorrer as bordas, porém quando coloco para imprimir exibe alguns valores estranhos. Acredito que acessei região da memória indisponível.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
void ConstroiTabuleiro(){
    // Aloca espaco na memoria para o tabuleiro
    tabuleiro = new int*[N+3];
    for(int i= 0; i <= N; i++){
        tabuleiro[i] = new int[N+3];
    }

    // Define as bordas como -1
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
       tabuleiro[0][i]  = -1;
       tabuleiro[i][0]  = -1;
       tabuleiro[i][N]  = -1;
       tabuleiro[N][i]  = -1;
    }

    // Inserindo NxN pecas aleatorias no tabuleiro
    for(int i= 1; i < N; i++){
        for(int j= 1; j < N; j++){
            tabuleiro[i][j] = rand()%D+1;
        }
    }

}

void ImprimeTabuleiro(){
    for(int i= 0; i <= N; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j <= N; j++){
            cout<<setw(3)<<tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

PS.: Na `main()` eu recebo apenas os valores de `N`, `D` e `S` que é a seed para a função `rand()`, essas variáveis são globais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Inserindo NxN pecas aleatorias no tabuleiro
for(int i= 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    for(int j= 0; j <= N; j++)
    {
        //  Se for a primeira linha OU coluna OU a ultima linha OU coluna
        //  adiciona -1
        if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == N || j == N)
            tabuleiro[i][j] = -1;
        else
            tabuleiro[i][j] = rand()%D+1;
    }
}
```

Basta adicionar -1 nas primeiras e ultimas linhas e colunas.

Lembre-se de adicionar +2 ao N.

Comment: `i` e `j` nunca serão 0 ou `N`.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Obrigado. copiei o for dele sem modificar.

Comment: Oi @LiquidPenguin , obrigado por responder. Eu testei o seu código aqui, e quando imprimiu o tabuleiro as bordas ficaram certas, porém somente N-1 linhas e colunas foram preenchidas com os números aleatórios. O que eu pretendo fazer é deixar as N linhas e colunas números normais, e as N+1 com `-1`.

Comment: @OtavioAugusto Você adicionou mais duas linhas e duas colunas?

Comment: @LiquidPenguin Sim, pro caso  `N = 5`, a matriz deveria ser `7x7`, porém ela fica `6x6`.

Comment: O problema é quando faço `tabuleiro =  new int*[N]` e depois faço o for para alocar um vetor para cada ponteiro e depois imprimo, aparece exatamente a matriz N x N. Pra ser sincero, eu nunca aloquei memória dinamicamente dessa forma. Sempre usei o `malloc()` e o `sizeof`, mas fui testar para esse caso e também deu erros de compilação.

Comment: Eu descobri o que estava errado. Os meus for's estavam assim: `for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)`. E quando eu declaro o tabuleiro como sendo `N+2 x N+2`, sua última posição será a `6`. Contudo, meus for's vão só até 5, então fica faltando a última linha e coluna para serem definidas como `-1`. Portanto devo percorrer até a posição `N+1`.